# C++ - Resizing a dynamic array

Tags: c++

**SOLVED**

I'm having problems with resizing an array of pointers, mainly with the last few lines of the AddGraphicElement() function.

I have the following class definition for a **VectorGraphic**:

```
unsigned int numGraphicElements;
GraphicElement* pElements;
public:

VectorGraphic();
~VectorGraphic()
{
    if (pElements)
        delete[]pElements;
}
void AddGraphicElement();
void DeleteGraphicElement();
void ReportVectorGraphic();
```

The following class definition for a **GraphicElement**:

```
static const int SIZE = 256;
public:
unsigned int numLines;
Line* pLines;
char name[SIZE];
GraphicElement()
{
    numLines = 0;
    pLines = nullptr;
}
~GraphicElement()
{
    if (pLines)
        delete []pLines;
}
```

And the following function **AddGraphicElement()** in the **VectorGraphic** class:

```
unsigned int numLines;
char name[256];
cout << "Adding a Graphic Element" << endl;

//Name input
cout << "Please enter the name of the new GraphicElement(<256 characters): ";
//Flush cin so it doesnt skip getline
cin.ignore(); 
cin.getline(name,sizeof(name));

//Line input
cout << "How many lines are there in the  new GraphicElement? ";
cin >> numLines;

//Allocate memory for line(s)
Line* pLines = new Line[numLines];

for(int i=0;i<numLines;i++)
{
    //Start point input
    cout << "Please enter the x coord of the start point of line index " << i << ": ";
    cin >> pLines[i].start.x;
    cout << "Please enter the y coord of the start point of line index " << i << ": ";
    cin >> pLines[i].start.y;
    //End point input
    cout << "Please enter the x coord of the end point of line index " << i << ": ";
    cin >> pLines[i].end.x;
    cout << "Please enter the y coord of the end point of line index " << i << ": ";
    cin >> pLines[i].end.y;
}

//Allocate new size for GraphicElement*
GraphicElement* newElements = new GraphicElement[numGraphicElements+1];

//Copy old elements to new pointer
for(int i=0;i<numGraphicElements;i++)
{
    newElements[i] = pElements[i];
    newElements[i].pLines = pElements[i].pLines;
}

//Assign new element to last index
strcpy(newElements[numGraphicElements].name, name);
newElements[numGraphicElements].numLines = numLines;
newElements[numGraphicElements].pLines = pLines;

//Re-assign the pointer and increment number of elements    
delete[] pElements;
pElements = newElements;    
numGraphicElements++;
```

Everything up until the last 3 lines seems to work fine. If I print the contents of newElements (before the delete and reassignment), all of my data is there. However, if I print it after delete and reassignment, my data is lost (the junk value -17891602 is there instead).

I don't think I'm using delete[] correctly since removing this line lets my program work, albeit with memory leaks:

```
delete[] pElements;
```

I suppose what I'm asking is how do I properly use delete[] in my program?

Thanks!

EDIT: SOLVED, NEW CODE FOR LOOP BELOW

```
    strcpy(newElements[i].name, pElements[i].name);
    newElements[i].numLines = pElements[i].numLines;

    Line* newLines = new Line[newElements[i].numLines];
    newLines->start.x = pElements[i].pLines->start.x;
    newLines->start.y = pElements[i].pLines->start.y;
    newLines->end.x = pElements[i].pLines->end.x;
    newLines->end.y = pElements[i].pLines->end.y;

    newElements[i].pLines = newLines;
```

Comment: What you want to do is separation of concerns. Your class shouldn't manage dynamic arrays, it should use something that does the management for you. That something is `std::vector`.

Comment: What is [The Rule Of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)? Read the link and find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete `pElements` it is deleting each `GraphicElement` object in there. When you delete a `GraphicElement` it deletes its `pLines` member. That's fine, except when you copy the data from `pElements` into `newElements` you only copy the `pLines` pointer value. So all of the old `GraphicElement` objects in `pElements` **and** the ones in `newElements` point to the same location. You then delete that location giving you the undefined behavior you're seeing. You need to do a deep copy.